Automatic index creation - too many
When we have the auto tuning set to ON for index creation, the Azure SQL Hyperscale db has created about 10 indexes for some of our large tables. In analyzing the indexes, some of them differ only in the 'included' columns while the index columns were same. This index proliferation will hurt the INSERT, UPDATE operations on such tables.
Is there an option in Azure to combine/optimize indexes, rather than us manually dropping and re-creating better indexes for many tables? As of now, turning off the auto index creation seems the only thing to do.
Are there other suggestions ?


In analyzing the indexes, some of them differ only in the 'included' columns while the index columns were same

This auto-indexing feature can be good in a situation if you don't have any DBA (developer, sysadmin, etc.) at all,  who can maintain indexes manually by checking missing index DMVs and figuring out how to combine suggested index combinations into indexes that would benefit most of the queries.

Is there an option in Azure to combine/optimize indexes, rather than us manually dropping and re-creating better indexes for many tables?

Unfortunately the feature is not smart enough to do that "human" part of the job at this time. It will create indexes, as you mentioned, that "some of them differ only in the 'included' columns while the index columns were same".
If you feel like many indexes that it creates really hurt INSERT and UPDATE operations, or use too much storage space, turn the feature off and maintain (create, modify, monitor usage of, drop) indexes manually.

Use this query to find the index using the most reads:
--- Index Read/Write stats (all tables in current DB) ordered by Reads  (Query 45) (Overall Index Usage - Reads)
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName]
    ,OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]) AS [ObjectName]
    ,i.[name] AS [IndexName]
    ,i.index_id
    ,s.user_seeks
    ,s.user_scans
    ,s.user_lookups
    ,s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups AS [Total Reads]
    ,s.user_updates AS [Writes]
    ,i.[type_desc] AS [Index Type]
    ,i.fill_factor AS [Fill Factor]
    ,i.has_filter
    ,i.filter_definition
    ,s.last_user_scan
    ,s.last_user_lookup
    ,s.last_user_seek
    ,'Show which indexes in the current database are most active for Reads' AS Info
FROM sys.indexes AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
    AND i.index_id = s.index_id
    AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
ORDER BY s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);-- Order by reads
    ------
    -- Show which indexes in the current database are most active for Reads

And then this to find the index that uses the most writes:
--- Index Read/Write stats (all tables in current DB) ordered by Writes  (Query 46) (Overall Index Usage - Writes)
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName]
    ,OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]) AS [ObjectName]
    ,i.[name] AS [IndexName]
    ,i.index_id
    ,s.user_updates AS [Writes]
    ,s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups AS [Total Reads]
    ,i.[type_desc] AS [Index Type]
    ,i.fill_factor AS [Fill Factor]
    ,i.has_filter
    ,i.filter_definition
    ,s.last_system_update
    ,s.last_user_update
    ,'Show which indexes in the current database are most active for Writes' AS Info
FROM sys.indexes AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
    AND i.index_id = s.index_id
    AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
ORDER BY s.user_updates DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);-- Order by writes
    ------
    -- Show which indexes in the current database are most active for Writes

Do you think you are missing indexes? Use this query to find missing indexes:
-- http://www.dharmendrakeshari.com/find-missing-indexes-sql-server-databases/

SELECT 
    migs.user_seeks as [Estimated Index Uses],
    migs.avg_user_impact [Estimated Index Impact %],
    migs.avg_total_user_cost[Estimated Avg Query Cost],     
    db_name(mid.database_id) AS DatabaseID,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME (mid.OBJECT_ID,mid.database_id) AS [SchemaName],
    OBJECT_NAME(mid.OBJECT_ID,mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
    'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(mid.OBJECT_ID,mid.database_id) + '_'
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
    + CASE
            WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL 
            THEN '_'
            ELSE ''
      END
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
    + ']'
    + ' ON ' + mid.statement
    + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'')
    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns 
    IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
    '' END
    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
    + ')'
    + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ') WITH (MAXDOP =?, FILLFACTOR=?, ONLINE=?, SORT_IN_TEMPDB=?);', '') AS [Create TSQL],
    mid.equality_columns, 
    mid.inequality_columns, 
    mid.included_columns,
    migs.unique_compiles,
    migs.last_user_seek 
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS migs WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig WITH (NOLOCK) ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid WITH (NOLOCK) ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
ORDER BY [Estimated Index Uses] DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);

Don't put random indexes on your database. They told you that the AI can do that automatically for you.
But this Azure feature that is supposed to find the right missing indexes has been there forever. Long ago this AI fenomen started.
Rest assured it will never help you.
